# How to convert an array of `DOMNode`s to a `DOMQuery` that holds exactly those nodes?

Tags: querypath

What is the idiomatic, efficient technique to construct a `DOMQuery` object that will contain the exact, caller-provided sequence of `DOMNode` objects? Detailed requirements:

- the `DOMNode` objects in the resulting collection must be **the** same objects as those provided; cloning of nodes is undesirable
- the method should be as efficient as possible

Things that don't work:

- `(new DOMQuery())->append($firstNode)->append($secondNode)`... will append to the elements of the collection, rather than to the collection itself
- `new DOMQuery($firstNode)` only works with one node, and there seems to be no way to add more nodes
- anything that involves `DOMDocumentFragment` launches its own horror story arc with a lot of predicted StackOverflow traffic

So, how do I?